# Good practice for placing Spring @Configuration for registering @Beans in context?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-bean, spring-config

I've decided I want to register Spring Beans in the java code and I want to know how it should be done the best way possible.

I inject deps through constructor (do not want to use @Autowire - I consider it almost antipattern) and I can make it work by adding:

```
@Configuration
 public class Config {
@Bean   
 public BeanType getBeanType() {
 return new BeanType();
 }
  }
```

BUT. Where the @Configuration part should go?

Should I make a Config class per package? (trying to make code closed in packages/domains)

Should I register them in inner classes of classed that are using them?

How should it be done? Internet is full of antipatterns, I want to find the way that is thought through carefully.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitated whether should I click on Close as it's opinion based but then decided to describe our practice.

We define multiple configuration classes and split them logically e.g. - one config for Db/hibernate/Transaction, another one for Queue/Listeners etc., one more for Logs and all related, plus one for No SQL connect etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what with beans such as facades? I assume you put them all in one place for a project as it was a practice in many applications with .xml based bean configuration?

I can agree, it can be opinion based but some opinions are more thought through then the others :)

Comment: The main rule for me is to have possibility easily add/remove configs. E.g. I would like to introduce No SQL - Mongo. It would be separate config. So I can exclude it from e.g. tests.

Comment: Nice point, thanks. Readability and easy exclusion for testing is a clear idea indeed.